# One Move Controller for 2 players?

Tags: playstation-move

Can you play some games like bowling and Sports Champion on ps3 with 1 controller for 2 people by passing the move controller around?

**UPDATE**


After buying Brunswick Pro Bolwing myself, i learned that it is ONLY pass-and-play. You cannot use more than one controller. In addition, and this is completely off topic, the game is horrible. Not at all realistic, and I know because I'm a highly active league bowler for the past 5 years with averages ranging from 190 or higher. Haven't checked High Velocity yet, but I will comment here when I do.

I also have purchased Sports Champion. Some games are pass-and-play, some are not. Basically any sport were you take turns is pass-and-play, all others require 2 controllers. I.E.:


Disc Golf: Pass-and-Play

Table Tennis: 1 Controller Per Person

Comment: The term you're looking for is `Hot Seat`.  :)

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [PlayStation blog](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2010/09/07/playstation-move-the-ultimate-faq/): Yes, some games do have this option. What you are looking for is **pass-and-play multiplayer**.

> **Q: How many PlayStation Move motion controllers do I need?**
>   A: Most PlayStation Move games only require one motion controller. However, some games may support two controllers for single-player gameplay (such as The Fight: Lights Out and certain events in Sports Champions) or for multiplayer mode.
>
> **Q: How many players can use PlayStation Move at the same time?**
>   A: The actual number of players supported depends on the game you are playing. Many PlayStation Move titles support anywhere from 1 to 4 players with many options for gameplay, including single player, pass-and-play multiplayer, competitive, or co-op modes. The PS3 system supports up to seven devices, of which up to four of those devices can be PlayStation Move motion controllers.

Sports Champions [does support pass-and-play](http://store.sony.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10551&storeId=10151&langId=-1&partNumber=PS398177).

> Sports Champions supports 1-4 players through intuitive, pass-and-play gameplay or head-to-head challenges.

High Velocity Bowling does not specifically mention it, but reviews I have read suggest that it supports pass-and-play. Brunswick Pro Bowling doesn't mention it either, and I can't tell from reviews whether or not pass-and-play is supported.

If there is a specific bowling game you're asking about that isn't listed, add that to your question and we'll see if we can find out whether or not pass-and-play is supported for that game.

Comment: I would prefer Brunswick as I am a serious bowler myslef, but i'll take either one if it supports pass-and-play.